# why is function of division not returning the correctly?

Tags: python, recursion

I have written some code below that is meant to print our how many times some integer n can be divided by a divisor:

for example if n = 100, divisor = 2   output = 6.  (as 100 can be divided by 2, 6 times)

```
def divisions(n, divisor):
    division_counter = 0
    n2 = n // divisor
    if n2 != 1:
        division_counter += 1
        n2 = divisions(n2,divisor)

    else:
        return division_counter

    return n2
```

The question I have is with the last line of code- what should I be returning?- is it correct to return n2? My thought behind this is that this will execute after every if statement, and so by the way I have defined n2, this will cause a recursion of the function divisions().

And the recursion will break, and thus 'else' statement will print when n2 == 1, which will always happen eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the counter to 0 every time you go into the function. Instead, pass the counter along to each successive call. I've also fixed the off-by-one error below (`if n2:`) as the test case was producing 5 rather than 6.

```
def divisions(n, divisor, counter=0):
    n2 = n // divisor
    if n2:
        counter += 1
        n2 = divisions(n2, divisor, counter)
    else:
        return counter
    return n2
```

```
>>> divisions(100, 2)
6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go with recursion [@Tigerhawk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67021527/14867730) or you can go with iteration method as per my logic,

1. Just iteration with condition up to `dividend` become `0` by this operation `n //= divisor`.
2. And finally return number of iteration takes place

Check out this code

**Method-1:**

```
def divisions(n, divisor):
    for i in range(n):
        n //= divisor
        if not n :
            return i

print(divisions(100, 2))
```

**Method-2:**

```
def divisions(n, divisor):
    number = 0
    condn = True
    while condn:
        n //= divisor
        if n:
            number +=1
        else:
            return number

print(divisions(100, 2))
```

If a number is very large you can go with this method:

**Method-3**

```
from math import log
n = 100
k = int(log(n, 2))

print(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

First step to set the result for boundary condition which to end the recursion.

for example:

```py
if n < divisor:
    return 0
```

If not, final result should one more times than result of `divisions` for new_n is `n//divisor`

So full code

```py
def divisions(n, divisor):
    if n < divisor:
        return 0
    return 1 + divisions(n//divisor, divisor)

print(divisions(100, 2))    # 6 for 100, 50, 25, 12, 6, 3
print(divisions(100, 3))    # 4 for 100, 33, 11, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so we should avoid things like mutation, variable reassignment, and other side effects. We can rewrite this using [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) -

1. if `n` is smaller than the `divisor`, no more divisions are possible. return the `counter`
2. (inductive) `n` is greater than or equal to the `divisor`, so at least one division is possible. return the result of the sub-problem `(n // divisor, divisor, counter + 1)`

```py
def divisions(n, divisor, counter = 0):
  if n < divisor:
    return counter                                        # 1
  else:
    return divisions(n // divisor, divisor, counter + 1)  # 2
```

---

A simple variation removes the unnecessary `counter` variable -

1. if `n` is smaller than the `divisor`, zero divisions are possible. return `0`
2. (inductive) `n` is greater than or equal to the `divisor`, so at least one division is possible. return `1` + the result of the sub-problem `(n // divisor, divisor)`

```py
def divisions(n, divisor):
  if n < divisor:
    return 0                                     # 1
  else:
    return 1 + divisions(n // divisor, divisor)  # 2
```

Comment: This answer originally posted as supplement to TigerHawk's answer. He/she removed it for unknown reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using `math.log`:

```
import math
def divisions(n, divisor):
    return math.floor(math.log(n,divisor))
```